# Prove that a prime number either divides an integer or is relatively prime to it

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Q. Let $p$ be a prime number and $a$ be any non-zero integer. Prove that $p|a$ or $(p,a)=1$.

I know that the proof is probably trivial but I'm not getting it.

Attempt: Let $a>p$. I know that $(p,a)=1\iff \exists m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $mp+na=1$. When $p\nmid a$, if we can find some $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ which satisfy the above, we are done. But I am able to use the fact that $p$ is a prime to prove the aforementioned?

Comment: This sounds like it needs the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and not much more.

Comment: Just to identify an example of the issue for non-primes: if $p=6$ and $a=8$ then $p$ does not divide $a$ but they are not coprime

Comment: @Henry True....

Comment: The gcd of $p$ and something is certainly a divisor of $p$. But $p$ only has two positive divisors.

Comment: @Randall I see, correct. So $a$ can be written as a unique product of prime numbers. So the factorization has $p$ in it or doesn't. If it doesn't, then since all the prime factors of $a$ are coprime with $p$, $a$ is also coprime with $p$?

Comment: Right.  $\gcd(a,p)$ is either $1$ or $p$.  If it's $p$, $p$ must divide $a$.

Comment: All the pieces of the proof are here in the comments; I wanted to add that there's no need to invoke prime factorization—only the definitions of divisibility and the gcd. Side note: the step $a>p$ in the OP's attempt isn't necessary—no argument depends on it.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(p,a)$ divides $p$. So, as $p$ has only the two divisors $1$ and $p$, it follows that $(p,a)$ must be either $1$ or $p$.

Now if on the one hand $(p,a)$ is $p$ however, then as $(p,a)$ divides $a$ as well, it follows that $p=(p,a)$ divides $a$, or in particular $p|a$.

If on the other hand $(p,a)$ is not $p$, then from the top paragraph, $(p,a)$ must be $1$. So by definition $p$ and $a$ are relatively prime.